# Extract c function with goto or break

Tags: legacy, automated-refactoring

On C project I currently work at there is much code that uses goto and break for error handling. Break and goto are usually found inside

```
if (error_occured) {
    LOGGER_REPORT_ERROR();
    goto cleanup;
}
```

I tried extracting code that includes chunks like this with Eclipse CDT refactoring but it did not work automatically.

This should be theoretically possible to do this automatically if additional error code variable is created in original function and extracted function returns error code somehow.

Is there an IDE or IDE plugin for automatic refactoring that supports such function extractions already?

Comment: To clarify: this goto jumps _out of_ a function? Why does it seem like a bad idea?

Comment: You could throw a `GotoPerformedException` expection that would contain the label name and catch it where you intend to jump if the goto jumps out of a function and rethrow if it's not the correct label.

Comment: Alternatively, you could always return a `CppEvent` which is either a `CppReturnEvent` or a `CppGotoEvent` if you are going to make your own refactorizer (or, in this case, it should be called compiler).

Comment: Jumps within a function can be rewritten by holding a `gotoTarget` variable and `switch`ing on that variable. If a `goto` is performed, set the `gotoTarget` and `continue` to the main `switch`.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to find an existing IDE that can convert a valid C code with goto's to Java, but you can create your own.

Comment: It sounds like you want to emulate an exception system.   I assume there's a chain of "cleanup" code chunks, one per function... is cleanup in one function supposed to pass control to cleanup in the parent?

Comment: Cleanup chunks are supposed to be one per function, there should be no gotos that lead out of your function.

Comment: Its unclear what you really want.  In most C dialects, you can't write a goto that escapes the function so your C programs already satisfy that constraint.  I suggest show an example of a function that is poorly constructed from your point of view, and what you want done to it to fix it.

Comment: @JanDvorak:  Where do OP hint that he was converting C code to Java?

Comment: ... are you going to show us an example of what you want?